# If statement isn't printing

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm a beginner in python and coding in general.

I was messing around with if statements and whenever I ran this code, it would never print what I asked it to, it would only print what was in the else statement.

I'm putting my code down below and if someone could help me understand the issue that'd be great, thanks!

```
canyou = input("Can you make a good meal on your own? ")
canyou1 = input("Can you wash your clothes well? ")
canyou2 = input("Can you clean the house properly? ")

if canyou.upper == "no" and canyou1.upper == "no" and canyou2.upper == "no":
    print("You need your mama")
else:
    print("You don't need your mama")
```

Comment: call `.upper` as a function `.upper()` (though perhaps you meant `.lower()` instead?)

Comment: Yeah, and "no" is lower case and willl never match anything uppercase

Comment: Also, you probably mean to use `or` instead of `and` unless you only need to be able to do one thing to not need your mama.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the uppercase string to a lowercase example. To fix this you can do the following

```py
if canyou.lower() == "no" and canyou1.lower() == "no" and canyou2.lower() == "no":
    print("You need your mama")
else:
    print("You don't need your mama")
```

You also need to call the method by adding parenthesis after `upper`/`lower`, as shown in my example.

Comment: this won't work because it only corrects the first instance to a call! `()`

Comment: @ti7 sorry yes I missed those ones, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method of each string like this:

```py
canyou = input("Can you make a good meal on your own? ")
canyou1 = input("Can you wash your clothes well? ")
canyou2 = input("Can you clean the house properly? ")

if canyou.lower() == "no" and canyou1.lower() == "no" and canyou2.lower() == "no":
    print("You need your mama")
else:
    print("You don't need your mama")
```

Also you need to call `.lower()`